# iPhone device attitude changes constantly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, rotation, direction

I noticed that if I call the startDeviceMotionUpdates method of the CMMotionManager class and then rotate the device and put it back on the table the reported device attitude is changing constantly, every time the reported rotation matrix is different from the last time. Has anyone else noticed the same behavior ?

Comment: How different is each successive matrix?

Comment: @Lou It shows about 10 degrees of rotation around z axis when being still on the table in 2 minutes with update rate of 100 Hz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently drifting of the gyro reference frame is a common issue and this is because it computes current attitude by aggregating rotation rates around axes over time

Comment: Do you have a link to any file or reference which might be useful backing up your answer?

Comment: @C4-Travis no specific link, but you can search for intertial navigation systems and their errors, and the fact that from time to time they need to be checked with an external source. I noticed the drift is only occuring in yaw component and I'm trying to fix it by taking into account the magnetic field that is an external source.